# PYTHON - TRY: ARGV STILL ERRORS OUT

Tags: python-3.x, argv, sys, index-error

Just trying to handle some `IndexError` while using `sys`. Searched a lot on how to do it, and I've come to a final "solution", but I don't know why it's not working.

Actual code

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

t = sys.argv[1]
u = sys.argv[2]

try:
    t = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print("no arg 1")

try:
    u = sys.argv[2]
except IndexError:
    print("no arg 2")
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/try.py", line 9, in <module>
    t = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know why it errors out, since I have set previously the `sys.argv[1]` inside the try block

Could anyone help me out on this?

EDIT:

I was able to find a way around for this, which is, a separate script for different stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the `t` and `u` definitions above the two `try` blocks. Get rid of those and keep your `try` blocks and you should be good.

Comment: Sorry breakthatbass, it keeps failing. You sure about that ? I'm using python3 T_T

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the spurious statements at the start (i.e. outside of the `try` statement), I think you are misunderstanding how array subscripting works in Python.

Python arrays start from subscript `0` (not `1`).  For an array with 2 elements, their subscripts are `0` and `1`.  So your code should be:

```
import sys

try:
    t = sys.argv[0]    # <<<
except IndexError:
    print("no arg 1")

try:
    u = sys.argv[1]    # <<<
except IndexError:
    print("no arg 2")
```

---

> Searched a lot on how to do it ...

Can I point out that this is NOT a good way to learn to program ... or to find the bugs in your code.  You should not be searching for "solutions".  You should be reading your code, and looking at the evidence and trying to figure out what you have done wrong.

For example, the version of the code in your question actually produces this output:

```
$ ./test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    t = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It says that the error is on line 5.  Then you look at the code and see that line 5 is NOT in the `try:` statement.

Secondly, you should be consulting **reliable** resources on Python; e.g. the official documentation, a textbook, or a decent tutorial.   They will explain clearly how array subscripting works, for example.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I was to get it to work. Besides that, I was able to understand as well, that when I put `t = sys.argv[0]` inside the try block I'm already defining it.